# animationWithFrame is crashing in iOS 9.2.1

Tags: ios

I am writing a game and I am using animations. In iOS 9.2.1 my app crashes. Here is the code I am using:

```
[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:[CCAnimation animationWithFrame:animal.animalSpriteFramesTitle
                                                    frameCount:2
                                                         delay:0.5]
```

[image: crash log]

Comment: Add crash log@Giresh